# What are the new duties of the 4 varnas as per Saunaka & Bhargabhūmi?

Tags: puranas, caste-system, varna, itihasa

In the Puranas, Manu and his wife had many children and future generations **who changed their caste (varna) totally freely.** For example, in Brahma Purana Chapter 5 it is given:

> Vaivasvata Manu (apparently kshatriya) had nine sons, all equal to him in every respect. They were Ikṣvāku, Nabhaga, Dhṛṣṭa, Śaryāti, Nariṣyanta, Prāṃśu, Riṣṭa, Karūṣa and Pṛṣadhra.
>
> The sons of Nabhaga and Dhṛṣṭa were **originally Kṣatriyas who later on became Vaiśyas.**
>
> The two sons of Nabhaga (kshatriya) and Riṣṭa were **originally Vaiśyas who later became Brahmins.**

Translator Horace Hayman Wilson himself remarks while translating Vishnu Purana that "The existence of but one caste in the age of purity .... **is every where admitted.**"

The casteless age is also mentioned in Itihasa by Bhrigu Rishi. It's given in Mahabharata book 12, SECTION CLXXXVIII

> There is really no distinction between the different orders. The whole world at first consisted of Brahmanas. Created equal by the Creator, men have **in consequence of their acts, become distributed into different orders.**

Vishnu Purana (book 4) also has the same detailed story of this period....... Chapter 8 says it was ended by Rishi Shaunak:

> The son of Kṣatravriddha (kshatriya) was Suhotra, who had three sons, Kāśa, Leśa and Ghritsamada. The son of the last was Śaunaka (rishi), **who FIRST established the distinctions of the four castes.**
>
> Bhargabhūmi; from whom also **rules for the four castes were promulgated**

What were these new distinctions? This is definitely not stopping varna change since Shaunak's descendants were in different varnas Brahmins, Kshatriyas and Shudras (Vayu Purana 2 Chapter 30.4-5).

So what could it be?